# How do I fix the error Guild Object has no attribute 'guild_permissions"

Tags: python, discord.py

The following is the string that is giving me a problem:

```
@client.command(aliases=['unban'])
async def unban1(ctx, user: discord.User):
  guild = ctx.guild
  channel = ctx.message.channel
  embed4 = discord.Embed(
    title='Unbanning Member...',
    description= f"{user} has been unbanned.",
    colour=discord.Colour.teal() 
  )
  if ctx.author.guild.guild_permissions.ban_members:
    await channel.send (embed=embed4)
    await guild.unban(user=user)
    pass
```

I haven't ready much on the discord.py rewrite documentation so if this is a noob problem, forgive me but, please help! The problem giving me the error is on line 10.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Remove `.guild` its `Member.guild_permissions` not `Member.guild.guild_permissions`

```py
@client.command(aliases=['unban'])
async def unban1(ctx, user: discord.User):
  guild = ctx.guild
  channel = ctx.message.channel
  embed4 = discord.Embed(
    title='Unbanning Member...',
    description= f"{user} has been unbanned.",
    colour=discord.Colour.teal() 
  )
  if ctx.author.guild_permissions.ban_members:
    await channel.send (embed=embed4)
    await guild.unban(user=user)
    pass
```